# Secret Santa Javascript: How to get a shuffled array with the original indexes randomized so no positions are the same?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make a secret Santa where I have a list of the people participating and then I click only once on a button and in front of each name I get the name of the person they will give a gift to.
The requirements are that a person doesn’t get its own gift and only gives the gift once.

I have tried to shuffle arrays without creating new arrays and now I am trying to implement the following logic (full code at the end):

- I have an array with the persons participating: *giveArr*
- I copy this array and call it *toReceiveArr*
- With a loop I go through the *toReceiveArr* and remove the *personGiving* from the

```
var toReceiveArr
var personGiving = toReceiveArr.splice(j,0);
```

- the *personReceiving* the gift is taken randomly from the *toReceiveArr* and added to a 3rd array - *receivingArr* - where the names of the persons are placed in different positions than the original *giveArr* and so this is the randomized list

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*toReceiveArr.length);
var personReceiving = toReceiveArr[random];
receivingArr.push(personReceiving);
```

- After this I remove the person receiving the gift from the toReceiveArr and add the person giving the gift back to the toReceiveArr so it can be included in the next for loop and receive a gift

```
toReceiveArr.splice(random,1); 
toReceiveArr.splice(j,0, personGiving);
```

So in the end I want to have something like this:
giveArr = [jason, Michael, susan]
receivingArr = [Michael, susan, Jason]

However when I try this I still get repeated givers and people receiving its own gift. I am a beginner but so far I am having no problems with the HTML part or EventListeners. But the JS is failing. Where are my mistakes?

```
var give = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var giveArr= [];
var toReceiveArr = [];
var receivingArr =[];

for (var i=0; i<give.length; i++){
    giveArr.push(give[i].textContent); }
toReceiveArr = giveArr.concat();

for(var j=giveArr.length-1;j>=0;j--){ 
    var personGiving = toReceiveArr.splice(j,0); 
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()* toReceiveArr.length);
    var personReceiving = toReceiveArr[random];

    receivingArr.push(personReceiving); 
    toReceiveArr.splice(random,1); 
    toReceiveArr.splice(j,0, personGiving);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood from your question, you want an output array that has the names in the "li" tags with these two conditions:

1- we don't have repeated names

2- the name of each output array items must be different from the input array with the same position for example if the first name is "jason" the first item of output array could not be "jason".

for these question I used "filter()" method of javascript instead of "splice" method. you can read more about this method from the link below:

> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

here is the code:

```js
let give = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
let giveArr= [];
let receivingArr =[];


for (var i=0; i<give.length; i++){
    giveArr.push(give[i].textContent); 
}

let lastName = give[give.length - 1].textContent;

let lenghtVar = giveArr.length

// ------------------------------
// functions that are used in "filter()" javascript method
function stringCheck(str) {
    // this filter is used to force each li element not give "itself" name : jason:jason
    return str != giveArr[0];
}

function deleteCheck(str2) {
    // this filter is used to see that we don't have repeated name
    let lastItem = receivingArr.length - 1;
    return str2 == receivingArr[lastItem];
}

function deleteCheck2(str3) {
    // this filter is used to delete repeated name from search
    let lastItem = receivingArr.length - 1;
    return str3 != receivingArr[lastItem];
}

function lastCheck(str4) {
    // this filter is used to check that last name is used before we reach to last item in the for loop
    return str4 == lastName;
}
// ------------------------------


for (let i = 0; i<lenghtVar; i++) {
    if(i == lenghtVar-1) {
        /* this "if" checks that the last name has been used before the last iteration, otherwise it replace it with the one previous last name */
        let new3Arr = receivingArr.filter(lastCheck);
        if (new3Arr.length == 0) {
    
            receivingArr.splice(lenghtVar-2, 0, lastName);
            console.log(receivingArr);
            break;
        }
    }
    
    let newArr = giveArr.filter(stringCheck);
    let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()* newArr.length);
    receivingArr.push(newArr[randomNum]);
    
    let deletArr = receivingArr.filter(deleteCheck);

    while (deletArr.length>1) {
        /* this "while" loop is checking that we do not have repeated names */
         let new2Arr = newArr.filter(deleteCheck2);

         let randomNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random()* new2Arr.length);
         receivingArr.pop();
         receivingArr.push(new2Arr[randomNum2]);
         deletArr = receivingArr.filter(deleteCheck);

    }
    
    console.log(receivingArr);
    
    giveArr.push(giveArr[0]);
    giveArr.shift();
} // end of for
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>random-array</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="names">
   <ul>
       <li>jason</li>
       <li>Michael</li>
       <li>susan</li>
       <li>oliver</li>
       <li>jack</li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   
   <script src="javacode.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

the "receivingArr" array in the code is the "output" array that you can use for your own project. I tested the code with 3 and 5 "li" tag. each time that you refresh the browser it produces random list that has that 2 conditions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution, it works! Not gonna lie, I don't yet fully understand the application of the filters in the loop.
I understand now that I was using the splice wrongly when adding items to the array (because of the indexes), but would you know what is wrong with my original way of solving the problem?

Comment: I think one thing that could be helpful for you is learning about "javascript mutation", you can search for it. but in the case of your code, using methods like "splice" would change the original arrays, and if you use "console.log()" for those arrays, you will notice that the number of elements and the value of them are changing each time you use such a method, it is not just "splice" but some other "javascript" methods like "push" has this feature, on the other hand some other methods likes "filter and map" do not change the original array.